# n equidistant points on circumference of an Ellipse

Tags: computational-geometry

I want to generate a list of ***n*** coordinate points which are on the circumference of an ellipse. I wrote this code:

```
n = 150;

ellipseFunc[a_,b_,t_] := {(a*b*Cos[t]/Sqrt[b*b*Cos[t]*Cos[t] + a*a*Sin[t]*Sin[t]]), (a*b*Sin[t]/Sqrt[b*b*Cos[t]*Cos[t] + a*a*Sin[t]*Sin[t]])};

listell = Table[ellipseFunc123[4, 1, (i - 1)*2*Pi/n], {i, 1, n}];

Graphics[{Red, PointSize[0.01], Point@listell, Blue,Circle[{0, 0}, {4, 1}]}]
```

This results in an image like this

[image]

However, I want the ***n*** points to be equidistant on the circumference of the ellipse. The problem with this approach is that of taking equal angles to compute coordinates. I checked onto this [question for circle](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/44415/choosing-n-equidistant-points-on-a-circle-with-given-radius-and-center?lq=1). But most of the answers take similar approach which works well for a circle but not for an ellipse.

Comment: Now, which of [these](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8454) [two](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8970) is appropriate for your problem?

Comment: (In fact, things are slightly easier here than in the general case, since the elliptic integral of the second kind (`EllipticE[]`) is built-in.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As @JM pointed out, this has been discussed before. My favorite method was mentioned by [Vitaly Kaurov](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/13/vitaliy-kaurov) in [his answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/8457/27951) to this question: [Generating evenly spaced points on a curve](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8454/27951), and it relies on letting `ParametricPlot` do all the work for you by using the `MeshFunctions -> {"ArcLength"}` option (here I am using `ellipseFunc`, i.e. your own parametrization of the ellipse, with some arbitrary numbers):

```
points = Cases[
  Normal@
    (plot = ParametricPlot[
         ellipseFunc[10, 3, t], {t, 0, 2 Pi},
         Mesh -> 45, MeshFunctions -> {"ArcLength"}
       ]),
    Point[l_] -> l, Infinity
  ];

Show[
  plot, Graphics[{PointSize[0.015], Red, Point@points}],
  AspectRatio -> Automatic
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As a side note, `ParametricPlot` returns a form of `Graphics` that uses a `GraphicsComplex` object and "relative coordinates" (for lack of a better term). However, it is easier to deal with absolute coordinates, so I turned the `GraphicsComplex` into a plain `Graphics` object using `Normal` before extracting the `Point` expressions.

Comment: I use "indexed" and "actual" coordinates myself, not knowing if there is more standard terminology.

Comment: @J.M. I like "indexed": that makes sense to me. That's what I should call them from now on!

Comment: @MarcoB I just noticed that the ellipse looks like it always has a gap. In your image, it has a gap on the end of the ellipse on the right. A gap shows every time I try the code on an ellipse.

Answer (score 9):

J.M.'s suggestion to use `EllipticE` can be implemented like this:

```
sample[t_, {a_, b_}] := {a Cos[theta], b Sin[theta]} /. FindRoot[b EllipticE[theta, 1 - a^2/b^2] - t, {theta, 0}]

samples[n_, {a_, b_}] := Module[{perimeterLength},
  perimeterLength = 4 b EllipticE[1 - a^2/b^2];
  Table[sample[t, {a, b}], {t, 0, perimeterLength, perimeterLength/n}]
  ]

ListPlot@samples[45, {10, 3}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Of course, `ArcLength` can be used just as well, but I thought I should post this as it distinguishes this question from the previous ones.

Comment: C. E., nice! Thanks for putting this together; I was curious to follow up on that suggestion myself to see how it would be used. (+1)

Comment: We are fortunate here that *Mathematica* is able to evaluate the elliptic integrals when the parameter (second argument) is negative. In most other computing environments, the parameter is restricted to the interval $[0,1)$; in which case, the arclength function used is `a (EllipticE[t + π/2, 1 - (b/a)^2] - EllipticE[1 - (b/a)^2])`, and the circumference is thus `4 a EllipticE[1 - (b/a)^2]`. Note that in this formulation, the parameter is equal to the square of the ellipse's eccentricity.