# Is it possible to calculate perimeter of an ellipse?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Is it possible to integrate a function that would give the perimeter of an ellipse?

Comment: Something like `ArcLength[Circle[{0, 0}, {1, 2}]]` or `RegionMeasure[Circle[{0,0}, {1, 2}]]`?

Comment: [How to determine the arc length of ellipse?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/433094/380122)

Comment: Why using numerical methods when there are complete elliptical integrals implemented in *Mathematica*? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Circumference

Comment: @CarlWoll Do you know why I get two [difference answer](http://i.stack.imgur.com/q9ly4.png)?

Comment: I think they are equal under the assumption `a>0 && b>0`.

Comment: [A related question.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/97095)

Answer (score 5):

$c = 4 a \int\limits_{\theta = 0}^{\pi/2} \sqrt{1 - e^2 \sin^2(\theta)} d\theta = a \pi (2 + e^2)$,

where

$a$ is the semi-major axis length and $e$ the eccentricity.

```
c[a_, e_] := 4 a Integrate[1 + e^2 Sin[θ]^2, {θ, 0, π/2}]
```

You can visualize the ellipse by:

```
ellipseplotter[a_, e_] := 
 ParametricPlot[
  a {Cos[θ], e Sin[θ]}, {θ, 0, 2π}]

ellipseplotter[1, .5]
```

[image]

Comment: first formula shows one minus, but the same (?) formula in the definition of c says one plus... did I miss something?

Comment: $a \pi (2 + e^2)$ is **NOT** the perimeter. The integral you start with is correct but you have missed the `Sqrt` when evaluating this integral. The correct expression is `c[a_, e_] = 4 a Integrate[Sqrt[1 - e^2 Sin[θ]^2], {θ, 0, π/2}, Assumptions -> {0 < e < 1}]` which yields `4 a EllipticE[e^2]`

Comment: The `ellipseplotter` expression is a little misleading as well, the parametric equation of an ellipse is `{a Cos[θ], b Sin[θ]}` which is equivalent to `a {Cos[θ], Sqrt[1 - e^2] Sin[θ]}`. The equation that you have used represents an ellipse with eccentricity $\sqrt{1 - e^2}$ and not $e$

Answer (score 3):

To illustrate parametric approach and `ArcLength` (I acknowledge this was mentioned by @Carl Woll):

```
r[a_, b_, u_] := {a Cos[u], b Sin[u]}
perimeter[a_, b_] := 
 NIntegrate[
  Sqrt[FullSimplify[D[r[a, b, u], u].D[r[a, b, u], u]]], {u, 0, 2 Pi}]
Manipulate[
 ParametricPlot[r[a, b, t], {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
  PlotLabel -> 
   Grid[{{"perimeter:", perimeter[a, b]}, {Style["ArcLength", Bold], 
      ArcLength[r[a, b, u], {u, 0, 2 Pi}]}}], 
  PlotRange -> Table[{-3, 3}, 2]], {a, 1, 3}, {b, 1, 3}]
```

[image]